# How to add cropped custom header image?

Tags: theme-development, themes, images, headers, header-image

I don't see in my custom theme any option for uploading the header image (although there is a code for it in the header)
Do I need to register it somehow?

Also, I have a specific size I want to implement, is it possible to hard-crop the header image on upload? (I want it to be cropped, not resized with CSS)

**Solution I found:**

I used `custom_header_support`

```
$custom_header_support = array(
    'width' => 260,
    'height' => 300,
    'header-text' => false,
);

add_theme_support( 'custom-header', $custom_header_support );
```

Comment: Re: uploading header in custom theme: what code do you have? :::::: Re: hard crop: are there so many header images? Why don't you crop it in Photoshop?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do that by adding the function `add_image_size` in your functions.php file of the theme folder.

Read more on how to add `add_image_size` here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size